# Need assistance to create array data from fetched records

Tags: php, arrays, web-scraping

I have text file as attached([Text file link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=60E8038703C3B9!150&authkey=!AC6x6xzQVod9lP0&ithint=file%2Ctxt)) and also mentioned as below:

```
     053722                                    01 02      03   04      05 06      07    08   09   10     11      12    13    14    15   16   17    18  19 20 21 22 23 24 25        26 27 28 29 30 31
     ULUSOY                                    Pe Cu      Ct   Pa      Pt Sa      Ca    Pe   Cu   Ct     Pa      Pt    Sa    Ca    Pe   Cu   Ct    Pa  Pt Sa Ca Pe Cu Ct Pa        Pt Sa Ca Pe Cu Ct
 YAVUZ BARBAROS                               IBB IBB     AG   AG     IBB IBB    OME    DY   DY   DY    IBB     OME   OME   OME    AG   AG   AG   IBE III III III III III III III III III III III III III
Uc Tr/Fl/Snf: C/738/C1
Uc Sr/Lmt U: 41:35/0:00                                                              IST                            IST   IST   IST
Lnd Krt Bit Tr: 03DEC2016                                                           06:00                          06:00 06:00 06:00
                                                                                14:00                          14:00 14:00 14:00
```

Is there any way to fetch records in array like as mentioned below:

```
[0] =&gt; Array
            (
                [date] =01
                [day] = Pe
                [name] =IBB
                [sector_to] ="" 
                [arr_time] = ""
                [dep_time] =""

            )
.
.
.
[6] =&gt; Array
            (
                [date] = 07
                [day] = ca
                [name] = OME
                [sector_to] =IST 
                [arr_time] =06:00 
                [dep_time] =14:00 

            )
.
so on....
```

I tried to collect data by my self as mentioned below:

```
$data = array(); $dates = array(), $days = array();  $events  =array();
$times = array();
$lines = file('thy-roster.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/(\d{2})\s/', $line, $matches)) {
 $dates = $matches[0] 
    }
if (preg_match('/([a-z]{2})\s/', $line, $matches)) {
 $days = $matches[0] 
    }
if (preg_match('/([A-Z]{3})\s/', $line, $matches)) {
 $events = $matches[0] 
    }
if (preg_match('/(\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s/', $line, $matches)) {
 $times = $matches[0] 
    }
}
```

Then explode them by space but all array element after exploade($dates,$days, $events, $times) are in different array keys so unable to store in single array.Please advice good logic for this.

Comment: we need to get your real text file, to look for sperators : like tabulations...can you attach it or give us a link for ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis: Thanks for your reply..Can you me assist to attache text file? or can you give your email id where i can send...Plz

Comment: this thread can help you to attach files
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: This is the link:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=60E8038703C3B9!150&authkey=!AC6x6xzQVod9lP0&ithint=file%2ctxt

Comment: Just make another array to hold all the other arrays?

Comment: @tam: yes, to hold in single array, Or you can assist me different logic

Comment: @vin I can help you parse this text file if you want and put it all in an array like you are asking, but I really think this is not the right way to approach this. Where/who is writing the `event-data.text` file to begin with? I would *****strongly***** advise having that file be rewritten in JSON format for example.

Comment: @tam: text file have roster data which we get diff-diff company. they might be difference. but above is same format from one company and format will be same. and we can't ask to each to change the format. please advoice?

Comment: @vin, for dates, days, and events, since there are the same number of entries in each line, you can parse them properly. However, since the times are not set for each day, and they are not even the same number of characters apart, its just kind of thrown in there, I am not sure there is a good solution in terms of entering the times. Why can't you ask them to change the format? it would make life easier for everyone

Comment: @tam: you are correct. I told them...but they can't change the system which report this. Wel thanks for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94009/discussion-between-tam-and-vin).